# How to autocomplete a delegate in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, delegates, intellisense

How do you autocomplete a method signature based on a delegate? Or atleast get some help from intellisense in completing the method signature.

Some method has a delegate as one of its parameters, so I have to create the method, call me lazy but it's quite painful to copy paste the method signature from MSDN.

I recall that when you specify an event handler, Visual Studio has an autocomplete feature for you (by hitting tab), but I wonder if this is possible for other kind of delegates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this unless your are subscribing to an event. It can be a custom event of course.

But for other delegates not possible.

Comment: You could make a feature request at MS :)

Answer (score 8):

It is possible - just type the name of the new method where the delegate parameter is expected, press Ctrl+. (quick actions) and choose "Generate method...".

For example, you can do `Shell.Current.Navigated += GetDelegate;`, Ctrl+. (or click the quick actions icon ([image: intellisense icon]) and click "Generate Method". In this case, we'd get the following method generated:

```
private void GetDelegate(object sender, ShellNavigatedEventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Then just copy the signature from there and delete the generated method:

```
Shell.Current.Navigated += (object sender, ShellNavigatedEventArgs e) =>
{
};
```

Comment: I just wanted to add that this really does work. In VS 2017, I can simply type "test", hit Ctrl+. and an intellisense preview appears automatically showing the method signature. So it really is as simple as typing a few chars and pressing Ctrl+. Quick and easy. Great find!